# How to resolve SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I created Three migration tables user_container table is for storing user details, admin_table is for storing admin details, blog_table is for storing blogs .admin can create blogs so that's why i make a foriegn key relationship for admin to blogs table .when i try to migrate the tables i am getting the following error

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 'admin_table' (SQL: alter table `blogs_table` add constraint `blogs_table_admin_id_foreign` foreign key (`admin_id`) references `admin_table` (`id`))
```

please help me to fix this issue i am not getting where did i mistake..

migration table structure
[image]

`2021_08_11_170129_create_Blogs_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateBlogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('blogs_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->longText('image');
            $table->unsignedInteger('admin_id');
            $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admin_table');
            $table->timestamps();
            //$table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blogs_table');
    }
}
```

`2021_08_12_121933_create_admin_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateAdminTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('admin_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
            //$table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admin_table');
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear... How can you reference other table that was not created ? You are first creating `blogs_table` and then creating `admin_table`, so when you create `blogs_table` and run the migration, it will not exist `admin_table` to reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're setting up the foreign key `$table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admin_table');` the table admin_table doesnt exist yet.

Change the migration name of the admin_table to be run before that of the blog one.

`2021_08_11_121933_create_admin_table.php`

instead of

`2021_08_12_121933_create_admin_table.php`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to run the migration on your Blogs Table first and after that, you run the migration on Admin Table.

Laravel migration takes the timestamp at the beginning of the file to decide which migration should be migrated first in the sequence.

Make sure you create an admin table first before the Blog table (this also applies to any tables that have references). Or simply just rename the file (change the timestamp) like E.g:

```
2021_08_12_121933_create_admin_table.php
2021_08_11_170129_create_Blogs_table.php
```

To this:

```
2021_08_11_121933_create_admin_table.php
2021_08_12_170129_create_Blogs_table.php
```

Then run `php artisan migrate:fresh` to refresh your migration.

Comment: @DevopsTraining you should not be getting errors with this solution, you need to rename both files

Comment: You are also right, that is also ok if we rename both files.